# Running commands in shell scripting

Tags: java, linux, shell

I have a very simple shell script which is meant to compile and run a `.java` file.

```
#!/bin/sh
x-terminal-emulator
javac SomeJavaFile.java
java SomeJavaFile
```

However this script seems to stop before it fires the `Java` commands. In essence the script may as well look like this

```
#!/bin/sh
x-terminal-emulator
```

How would I be able to fix this problem?

**Edit**

As per suggestions and answers my script now looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh
x-terminal-emulator -e "javac DropboxStatusLoop.java && java DropboxStatusLoop"
```

However it opens then closes instantly. I think this is strange since there is a loop going in my code.

Very simplistically, my code looks like this

```
import java.lang.*;

public class SomeJavaFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(long i = 0; ; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Hi");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It does compile and run properly when done manually, however, it has the same problem with the terminal opening and closing which was mentioned before. I believe this is because of `Thread.sleep(1000);` which may make the terminal think it has finished what it is doing so it stops and closes. Any help in fixing this is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to do `x-terminal-emulator`?

Comment: @cricket_007 I was told to use this as it opens the default terminal

Comment: Told by who? If you just run `./your-script.sh` after a `chmod +x ./your-script.sh`, then your java code will run in the current terminal. There is no reason to create a new one.

Comment: @cricket_007 I see the confusion. What I have done is set it so that the script file is ran when it is double clicked so what I am trying to do is launch a terminal and then compile and run the java program. There is no current terminal

Comment: I'm fairly sure that Kali will open a terminal for you when you click to open any shell file.

Comment: @cricket_007 Unfortunately it is not

Comment: @cricket_007 would you be able to help further based off the edit?

Comment: I think you need `DropboxStatusLoop.java && java DropboxStatusLoop`. The way you have will put the compiling task in the background and immediately try to run the code without finishing compilation.

Comment: Dan, I'm sorry for the typo, it should be `&&` not `&`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass commands as input to another command (su, ssh, sh, etc)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586811/pass-commands-as-input-to-another-command-su-ssh-sh-etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Script fixes

This section highlights problems with the script itself, and does not touch on the bug with Linux that was also a problem. If you are reading this answer at a later date and you are only having problems with executing the script, see the below section **"Bug fix for Linux, Nautilus users"** or see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/286621).

- The problem is that your script will run `x-terminal-emulator` which opens a new instance of a terminal, then it waits for that process to finish before continuing. There isn't anything that will make it finish though, it will just open and wait.

The `Java` compiling and running commands aren't passed to `x-terminal-emulator`, rather they are simply commands in your script that are executed after `x-terminal-emulator` finishes running.

- Also, since you don't want to run the java program unless it successfully compiles, you should chain the commands together like this: `command1 && command2`. This way, `command2` is only ran when `command1` is successful.

To pass the `Java` commands to run in `x-terminal-emulator`, use the `-e` option like this:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "javac SomeJavaFile.java && java SomeJavaFile"
```

This will send the commands to `x-terminal-emulator`.

- Unless you specifically want to open *another* shell when this program runs, you most likely don't want to use `x-terminal-emulator`.

Simply remove that line from the script so the entire script becomes:

```
#!/bin/sh
javac SomeJavaFile.java
java SomeJavaFile
```

- You must make sure that you have followed the steps to make your shell script executable, otherwise it must be ran from the terminal with the `bash` or `sh` command.

---

## Making the script executable

To be able to run the script by double-clicking its icon, or by typing `./script.sh`, you need to:

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

Where `script.sh` is the name of your script file.

```
chmod +x myScript.sh
```

And include the "she-bang" line at the top of your script file:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Then you can double click its icon, or run it with `./myScript.sh`.

---

## Bug fix for Linux, Nautilus users

After finding the problems with the author's script, the solution still did not work because of a "bug" with Kali Linux, related to a bug with Nautilus in all Linux distributions.

To fix the bug, all of the steps in the "Making the script Executable" section have to be followed, as well as this next one.

#### What is the issue?

The default behavior of Kali Linux is to run executable shell scripts in the background, if they were clicked on (ran from the desktop or file explorer).

The default behavior of Nautilus, the default file explorer in most Linux distributions, is to open an executable shell script for editing when it is opened.

This explains why the author's script worked perfectly when they ran it from the terminal with `./script.sh` or `bash ./script.sh`.

#### The fix

After following the steps in the section "Making the script Executable", you need to change a setting within Nautilus. This solution was found [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/286621), where it is talked about with more depth.

Here is the gist of the solution:

- Open the file explorer, Nautilus, by opening any folder or typing `nautilus`. Then go to this menu:

  ```
   Edit → Preferences
  ```
- Then go to the `Behavior` tab, and under `Executable Text Files`, select **`Ask each time`**. For non-Kali users, I do think that you can select `Run executable text...` as the default option.

[image: Nautilus GUI showing where to find the "Ask Each Time" option]

**Kali must** be configured to **`Ask each time`** an executable shell script opened, choosing "Run executable text files..." **will not work!** But, I do think that with other distributions you can choose "Run executable text files...." to be the default behavior.

---

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this causes yet more problems. Would you be able to help further based off the edit?

Comment: @Dan, when you tried to make the shell script without the `x-terminal-emulator` part, did you make sure to make the file executable?

Comment: @Dan Read the last part of my answer (newly edited) and let me know if that changes anything.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the typo. I have changed that now. I did make it executable using `chmod +x script.sh`. However all of this hasn't made any difference. It still opens and closes instantly. I am meant to put an extra command in the `-e` part so the terminal stays open?

Comment: @Dan, to make it easy to troubleshoot, I've added a new section to the bottom of my answer. Try the bit there and let me know what happens now.

Comment: Hello. I did what you said to do and when I type `./myScript.sh` it works no problem. When I double click on the file nothing happens. This is what led me to use `x-terminal-emulator` in my original attempt. I appreciate you taking the time to help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109465/discussion-between-matthew-cliatt-and-dan).

Comment: I must say, this is one of the best answers I have seen in a long time

Comment: @Dan Thanks Dan :) I try to put a lot of effort into my answers, so it's really nice to see that they help and are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

inside script, you are running a program "x-terminal-emulator" through script which is running in foreground.
Hence it is not returning control to main script.
Kindly remove that program from script if you just want to run java program through script.

```
#!/bin/sh
javac SomeJavaFile.java
java SomeJavaFile
```